# npm run serve get stuck on 40% while running

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js

It’s been a couple of weeks that I’m working on a Vue js project Vuetify to be specific. I use `npm run serve` command to build and run a live server. it was working fine everything was okay but suddenly I run my project again and boom can’t building anymore it gets stuck 40% without throwing anything as a bug or an error. I wanna know guys if you had similar issue like mine or if you know how to troubleshoot this issue. thank in advance.

I'm using `npm 6.9.0` , `node v10.16.0` and `vue 3.9.2`

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mycode",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "fuse.js": "^3.4.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.12.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-table-component": "^1.9.2",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your `package.json`?

Comment: *1 part*  {
  "name": "mycode",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "fuse.js": "^3.4.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.12.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-table-component": "^1.9.2",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.5"
  },

Comment: *2 part* ,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    }

Comment: I copied it to the question. It is just pending for a peer review

Comment: I just reproduced the following steps and everything seems to be fine: setup a new project with `vue create test`, replace the `package.json` with yours and run `npm install`

Comment: Is `npm install` working fine for you?

Comment: yeah, the **npm install**  is working fine cause i can create new project but if i run the previous project through **npm run serve**, it get stuck exactly on 40%

Comment: For me everything is working fine. Some error would be helpful...

Comment: actually there is no error popping up, it getting stuck only. i am trying to see how to send a screenshot but there is no option for that

Comment: in my cmd it's written  **INFO Starting development server... 40% building 160/181 modules 21 active ...ddProvider.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js** something like this

Comment: Are you using Git for versioning ? If yes, don’t hesitate to look for conflict markers (the ones with >>>>> on the whole line). I already had this issue before: the project couldn’t build because of these conflicts I forgot to resolve (and node doesn’t throw errors sometimes depending on which files you have these markers set).

Comment: You can try reinstalling `npm` and `@vue/cli` globally. Even before that please check if `npm cache verify` helps.

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes during the compiling process certain errors occur. For example say I have a component with a template that contains the following

```
<template>
  <imagingheader></imagingheader> 
  <router-view ></router-view>
</template>
```

Now what is wrong with this picture?

There are two base elements in the template. During the compiling process this will prevent it from going any further and sadly the server does not start to display this error.  Moving the two elements into a common div tag fixes the issue and moves the compling process from 40% to 100%.

Comment: This actually fixed my problem. Thanks !!

Comment: This helped me help a student with an obscure problem today. Thank you as well, helpful stranger from a pre-pandemic world.

Comment: For reference, the problem occured with our code because I forgot to set a value to a string property, writing only `:label` instead of `:label="myLabel"`

Answer (score 0):

Take some time and look through your code and see whether you will get a missing closing tag. It can be a missing , , ... etc.

Keep an eye on the first place the numbers pause and use that as a way to narrow down the problems you might face.

```
40% building 223/268 modules 45 active ...rders\List.vue?
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up wasting 30 minutes on a similar issue, to find out that I had a merge (due to `git pull`) in progress and there were conflicted filed :/